# Toolbar is not visible on Android 4.X devices

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I just updated android.support:appcompat lib to 22.1.1.

Toolbar is visible on a Lollipop device but not on a 4.X device.

I have even tried extending AppCompatActivity, but still no luck. If anything else is required please let me know.

Here is my project styles and base activity xml file.

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primarydark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/activity_bg</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

    </style>
```

**activity_base.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fulllayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:background="@color/primary">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/container">

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: android 4.4 emulator][image: android 5.0 emulator]

**Update :**

Issue is with layout inflated in container part. it is overlapping toolbar so i have removed all views and it worked.

Thanks all...

Comment: I guess you shouldn't extend from `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` which states in name, that there will be no ActionBar

Comment: @MarekSebera That is false. `NoActionBar` means that you must supply your own `Toolbar` to serve as the Action Bar.

Comment: Sounds very weird. Does it also not work well on 4.x emulators? Have you tried removing all the attributes you've set of "AppTheme.Base" ? Have you also tried running a sample project that just has the toolbar as the action bar ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper yes i tried removing all the attributes from "AppTheme.Base" but still no luck and for 4.3 emulator also it is not visible.

Comment: @androidnoobdev Try to create a totally new "hello world" project with the same stuff. I've had no such issues on my app, so it has something to do with extra stuff you have in yours.

Comment: @androiddeveloper in new project it is working fine. i don't know why not in my project.

Comment: @androidnoobdev OK, so now you have to add pieces from your project to the new one, to see what causes it to happen.

Comment: @androidnoobdev You should see about posting your solution if you solved this.

Comment: @Laurel actually it requires to put hole activity code here to explain solution that's why i haven't added in answer.