# Toolbar and TabLayout is not visible on Android 4.4 devices

Tags: android, android-viewpager, toolbar, android-appcompat, android-tablayout

I was trying to implement Toolbar and TabLayout using google design library by referring to [http://blog.grafixartist.com/material-design-tabs-with-android-design-support-library/] [blog].

Output works as expected on Lollipop devices but it doesnot show ToolBar and TabLayout on Kitkat devices. But i can still swipe through 3 fragment as expected on kitkat device as well. How come same code written using google support libraries works differently on different devices!

I tried referring to [[Toolbar is not visible on Android 4.X devices [solved]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29864524/toolbar-is-not-visible-on-android-4-x-devices-solved]) question but it didn't solve the problem. I tried running the code in emulator with API 19 but facing same issue on that as well.

I have added `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'`, `'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'` and `'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'` dependencies in the project.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tablayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public ViewPager viewPager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }
            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            }
        });

    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFrag(new QueuedFragment(), "Queued");
        adapter.addFrag(new IntransitFragment(), "InTransit");
        adapter.addFrag(new DeliveredFragment(), "Delivered");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

**style.xml**

```
<resources>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Can you post your styles file?

Comment: I have added style file. Please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: Why is the `TabLayout` height `match_parent `?

Comment: I tried changing it to wrap_content but still facing the same issue.

Comment: do u have solution for this ?

Comment: @srikanth yes I have. After adding windowActionBarOverlay property inside style.xml file, it is working fine now. Sorry for the late response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"//here
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tablayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

or:

```
 <style name="ParallaxTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks SilentKnight after adding windowActionBarOverlay property inside style.xml file, it is working fine now.

Answer (score 4):

this happened to me and it was because i was using a CoordinatorLayout but i was not specifying the *layout_behavior* of the content.  So you should do this in my case:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/cl_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:ignore="MissingPrefix">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="@color/white"
            app:titleEnabled="false">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                    fontPath="fonts/Medium-Extd.otf"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="my toolbar title"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<!-- add the behavior here and the toolbar apppeared on 4.4 devices in my case -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >

//...... blah blah

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had problem in Android 4 and I solved it. See how.
Need to move the toolbar to a higher level.

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >
    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



    <!--<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />-->

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the top layout parent in *activity_main.xml* is not a CoordinatorLayout (is there FrameLayout or RelativeLayout?) there may be some wrong different overlap depending on API version.
Change top layout parent to a CoordinatorLayout and it will work everywhere.

Comment: Top layout is CoordinatoLayout only but due to some editing issue it was not showing earlier. Could you please check it now and let me know if something is not right

Comment: change `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` to  `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

Comment: I changed it to "xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" but still i was facing the same issue and after adding "<item name="windowActionBarOverlay">false</item>" line inside style.xml file , as suggested by SilentKnight, it is working fine now.

Comment: In my opinion, was the wrong namespace for `app:`  prefix to produce the overlap.

Comment: i was facing same issue even after changing the app prefix so i think it was not because of that. But i am facing this problem again i might have to post another question again.

Answer (score 0):

Component Tree -> tablayout or toolbar -> Convert to ConstraintLayout it will work

Comment: Please elaborate your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) with some explanations.