# TabLayout tabs title not displaying in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-tablayout

The tabs are working in an app and shown tabs title correct,  design tab even after I set the `app:tabTextColor` attribute.

And I am excited because I don't see edit progress in the editor when adding new code.

**Main-Class:**

```
  enter code public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // Create an instance of the tab layout from the view.
        TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        // Set the text for each tab.
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(R.string.tab_label1));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(R.string.tab_label2));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(R.string.tab_label3));
        // Set the tabs to fill the entire layout.
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
        // Use PagerAdapter to manage page views in fragments.
        // Each page is represented by its own fragment.
        final ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        // Setting a listener for clicks.
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Pager Adapter:**

```
  public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {


    private int mNumOfTabs;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumberOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.mNumOfTabs = NumberOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        switch (i) {
            case 0: return new TabFragment1();
            case 1: return new TabFragment2();
            case 2: return new TabFragment3();
            default: return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNumOfTabs;
    }
}
```

**In an app:**  When I launch the app all looks like I expect.
[image]

**XML file** Main activity code.  Fragments files appear well and I not attached them.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/design_default_color_primary_dark"
        app:tabTextColor="#eac086"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout" />

</RelativeLayout
```

**Android Studio look like:**
[image]

**Gradle file:**

```
   android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.lateralnavigation"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: please add build a Gradle file of app-level where you add dependencies

Comment: please put this code above

Comment: added plz see above

Comment: @ Mykhailo Vasylenko change this line `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'`

Comment: have look this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49534777/android-studio-3-1-xml-preview-not-showing-for-some-xml-layouts)

Comment: @TanveerMunir changed dependencies, style, but nothing help. Other layouts display well but on the MainActivity XML response only on background colors changes into TabLayout.

Comment: look this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31344288/toolbar-and-tablayout-is-not-visible-on-android-4-4-devices) and use `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout`

Comment: you are generating tabs programatically that's why its not showing there if you want to show there please add tab items in XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the preview editor won't be able to tell what you've written in your java/kotlin code. It generates the preview from your xml, what you can do to preview  the tabs is to add them directly into the xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/design_default_color_primary_dark"
    app:tabTextColor="#eac086">
  <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
     android:text="@string/tab_text"/>
  <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
     android:text="@string/tab_text"/>
 <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
     android:text="@string/tab_text"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

This however will change how you inflate the layout as the tabs will already be in the xml. There won't be any need to do:

```
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(R.string.tab_label1));
```

As the tab will be in the xml, you'll only need to assign an id to it and use findViewById to actually access the tab. If you have a static number of tabs you can even use:

```
tabLayout.getTabAt(position)
```

To access a tab at a given position.

Comment: I know this variant, but it takes a lot of time, each time when I do some changes I must run the app to see TabLayout. Thanks for reply

Comment: Yeah, if you want to see the preview you'd need to use xml. Adding the tabs programatically will not show up in the editor preview.

Comment: @MykhailoVasylenko but if you wanna loot in design you must add tab items in XML